# Kivy: Text not showing

Tags: python, text, kivy

I'm having a strange issue with Kivy. I have a simple application with a button with text on it: `Hello World`.

The text does not appear or shows in a bad way. I have attached a picture so you can understand. Text not showing

[image]

This is the code of the app:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

TestApp().run()
```

I think it's something related to my Kivy configuration or dependencies, but I don't know what.

Comment: I think this is a known bug that has been fixed in kivy master, but I'm not sure why text_sdl2 doesn't work and is ignored. You may have better luck finding out on the kivy irc or mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue.  I found that I had to add the transparency parameter to the color property I.E. color: R,G,B,A so I had to add 1 for A

Answer (score 0):

For me, updating the pygame package using `pip install --upgrade pygame` fixed the problem